# Can not populate List<Item> from XML nodes

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I have an xml document to parse which have nested nodes I have tried in my way but unable to get job done as desired.
XML doc is

```
<Items>
   <Item>
   <MediumImage>
      <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51l7DDD1qNL._SL160_.jpg</URL>
      <Height Units="pixels">160</Height>
      <Width Units="pixels">160</Width>
   </MediumImage>
   <Title>Fallout 4 Vault Dweller's Survival Guide Collector's Edition: Prima Official Game Guide</Title>
   <OfferSummary>
   <LowestNewPrice>
   <Amount>1952</Amount>
   </OfferSummary>
   </Item>
   .
   .
   .
</Items>
```

I have done to fetch *Title* node values as

```
private static NodeList fetchTitle(String requestUrl) {
        NodeList nodeList = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(requestUrl);
            nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Title");            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Message is " + e.getCause() + "...." + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return nodeList;
    }
```

and I print as in main() as

```
titleList = fetchTitle(requestUrl);        
        for (int i = 0; i < titleList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = titleList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                // do something with the current element
                System.out.println(node.getNodeName()); 
                System.out.println("Signed Title is \"" + node.getTextContent() + "\"");
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
```

and *Amount* value from *LowestNewPrice* Node as

```
private static NodeList fetchPrice(String requestUrl) {
        NodeList nodeList = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(requestUrl);
            nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("LowestNewPrice");           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Message is " + e.getCause() + "...." + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return nodeList;
    }
```

and I print as in main() as

```
priceList = fetchPrice(requestUrl);

        for (int i = 0; i < priceList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = priceList.item(i).getFirstChild();
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                // do something with the current element
                System.out.println(node.getNodeName()); 
                System.out.println("Signed Price is \"" + node.getTextContent() + "\"");
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
```

through above code I get all *Title* values first and then I get *Amount* values separately, but what I really want is to have a POJO class as

```
public class Item {

    String title;
    String price;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

and add values to Item object using `setTitle(), setPrice()`, and return a `List<Item>` 
any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **might** try this solution please.
Parse your data and add to `List<Item>` as :

```
public static Document fetchRequiredData(String src) {
    Document doc = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder parser;

    try {
        parser = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc= parser.parse(src);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return doc;
}

public static List<Item>  parseItemInfo(Document doc){

    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    NodeList itemNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Item");       

    for (int i = 0; i < itemNodeList.getLength(); i++) {

        Node titleNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("Title").item(i);
        Node priceNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("LowestNewPrice").item(i).getFirstChild();

        if (titleNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE || priceNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setDesc(titleNode.getTextContent());
            item.setPrice(priceNode.getTextContent());
            items.add(item);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

now your List is ready to test in `main()` method as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<Item> items = parseItemInfo(fetchRequiredData(requestUrl));
     System.out.println("Printing List<Item> contents ...");
     for (Item item : items) {
         System.out.println("Title is " + item.getTitle()); 
         System.out.println("Price is " + item.getPrice());
         System.out.println();
     }
}
```

Hope this one helps.

Comment: This is an efficient way of doing it but it will fail in cases where there can be `<Item>` elements with no `<Title>` or `<LowestNewPrice>` elements.

Comment: As by provided _xml stub_ above in question I guess it is less likely to have any such cases where there can be `<Item>` elements with no `<Title>` or `<LowestNewPrice>` elements. Thanks for you consideration, but can above answer be __improved__ to avoid such cases, I think this answer is __easy__ to _read_, _write_ , _compile_ and get the desired job done. Isn't it...?

Comment: You're absolutely right, like I've said "this is an efficient way of doing it", I just wanted to point that out to make the OP aware of it so he can modify the code if his use case includes those kind of items.

Comment: Thanks for _appreciation_.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by using JAXBContext. First create Item class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Items")
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Items
{
    @XmlElement(name = "Item")
    private List<Item> item;

    public void setItem(List<Item> itemList)
    {
        this.item = itemList;
    }
    public List<Item> getItem()
    {
        return this.item;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Item")
@XmlAccessorType(vallue = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item
{
    @XmlElement(name = "MediumImage")
    private MediumImage image;
    @XmlElement(name = "Title")
    private String title;
    @XmlElement(name = "OfferSummary")
    private OfferSummary summary;

    getters();
    setters();
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "MediumImage")
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MediumImage
{
    @XmlElement(name = "URL")
    private String url;
    ....
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "OfferSummary")
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OfferSummary
{
    @XmlElement(name = "LowestNewPrice")
    private LowestNewPrice lowestPrice;
    ....
}
```

Then from the main method use marshaller and unmarshaller method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File xmlFile = new File("file path");
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);
    //To get POJO from xml
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Items items = (Items) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently it seems that you're separating the prices and titles into 2 lists, if you want to store an item's price and title into a single `Item` object, you can do something like this:

```
public class Item {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new File("items.xml"));
            NodeList itemElements = doc.getElementsByTagName("Item");

            for (int i = 0; i < itemElements.getLength(); i++) {
                Node itemElement = itemElements.item(i);
                NodeList itemChildren = itemElement.getChildNodes();

                Item item = new Item();

                for (int j = 0; j < itemChildren.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node n = itemChildren.item(j);
                    if (n.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        item.setTitle(n.getTextContent());
                    } else if (n.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("OfferSummary")) {
                        NodeList offerChildren = n.getChildNodes();
                        for (int k = 0; k < offerChildren.getLength(); k++) {
                            Node offerChild = offerChildren.item(k);
                            if (offerChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("LowestNewPrice")) {
                                item.setPrice(offerChild.getTextContent());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                items.add(item);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("items: " + items);
    }

    String title;
    String price;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Title: " + title + " Price: " + price;
    }

}
```

What this does is to get all the `<Item>` elements from the XML and loop through them to get the item's title and price.